# What does it mean to say that similar matrices represent the same linear map under (possibly) different bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example: how exactly do $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\\ 1 &0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -5/3 \\\ 3 & -2\end{pmatrix}$$ represent the same linear map?

I do understand how to express the same vector under different bases.

I believe my question is the same as [What does it mean to be the same linear transformation in different bases?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912394/what-does-it-mean-to-be-the-same-linear-transformation-in-different-bases)

However, I do not understand how the one current answer is meant to answer the question, which may very well be because I'm missing some insight as to the implications of the statements made in the answer.

I'm having trouble figuring out what it means to say that similar matrices represent the same linear map under (possibly) different bases.

Firstly, I don't even have a good guess as to what is meant by the basis corresponding to a particular matrix representation of a linear map.

I had the following idea as to one way to make the concept clear:

First, come up with two non-identical similar 2x2 matrices $A$ and $B$.

Then, point out the basis $\mathcal{A}$ corresponding to matrix $A$ and the basis $\mathcal{B}$ corresponding to matrix $B$ and explain why those would be the bases corresponding to $A$ and $B$ (again, I don't even know what it means for a basis to correspond to a particular matrix representation of a linear map).

Lastly, point out how exactly it is the case that the two matrices do in fact represent the very same linear map but under different bases.

I truly did go over a lot of linear algebra learning materials hoping to find an answer to my questions, but could not find anything that addressed these questions specifically, although I'm sure I probably did learn this a decade ago when I took a linear algebra course.

If possible, I'd greatly prefer that one of the two matrices be a very simple rotation or reflection matrix, for the sake of making it easier to understand that each of the two matrices represent the same linear transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Read this carefully to know what actually it means when we are saying that " A matrix representing a linear map"...

See, Let consider a linear map $T:V \rightarrow V$ where $V$ is finite dimensional  vector spaces(I am considering only one vector space for better explanation). Since, this vector space is finite dimensional vector space so it has a bases.

Now suppose dimension is $n$ and bases is $\beta=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n\}$. Remember domain and co domain both are same  V.S. and we are taking same bases for this calculation (We can take another bases for co domain since we have plenty of them)

Now, we find image of each element of this bases $\beta $ as then we get image vectors which are also element of $V$. Also we know that we can write this image vectors as a linear combination of bases vector as shown below..

$$ T(x_1)=y_1=a_{11}x_1+a_{21}x_2+\ldots a_{n1}x_n$$
$$T(x_2)=y_2=a_{12}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\ldots a_{n2}x_n$$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\vdots$
$$T(x_n)=y_n=a_{1n}x_1+a_{2n}x_2+\ldots a_{nn}x_n$$
Where, all $a_{ij}$ are scallars from the respective field.

Now, if write all these scallars into the form of matrix (we write scallars of the each linear combination as column of a matrix) then resulted matrix is known as matrix representing a linear map corresponding to bases $\beta$ and denoted as $A[\beta:\beta]_T$ which is ,

$$
A[\beta:\beta]_T=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots &a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots &a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Obviously,If we change the  bases $\beta$ then possibly we can get a different matrix but still this matrix also represents the same linear map. Also these different matrices have a connection which is known as similar matrices.

Comment: And yes if you consider vector  x of vector space as a column vector and multiply this with this matrix A, i.e. if we find Ax  then it gives same answer as T(x)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_1, \dots, u_n$ be a basis of a vector space $V$ and let $T$ be a linear transformation $V \to V$. Then we can write each $T u_i$ as a linear combination $\sum_j a_{ji} u_j$, so writing these coefficients as the $i$th column we get a matrix $A$. This is called the matrix representing $T$ in the basis $(u_i)$.

Now suppose $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is another basis of the same vector space $V$. Then the same recipe gives a new matrix $B$ representing $T$ in the basis $(v_i)$. We can ask what the relationship is between $A$ and $B$.

Note that we can also write each $v_i$ as a linear combination $\sum_j p_{ji} u_j$, and taking these coefficients to be the $i$th column we get an $n \times n$ matrix $P = (p_{ij})$. It is not hard to check that $PB = AP$, or $PBP^{-1} = A$, once you know that $P^{-1}$ exists, ie $P$ is invertible. In fact $P^{-1}$ is given by writing $u_i$ as linear combinations of $v_j$, inverting the recipe for $P$ as one might expect.

In this situation the matrices $A$ and $B$ are called similar.

---

To deal with your given example, let's say the first matrix $A$ is in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In other words, $T e_1 = e_2$ and $Te_2 = -e_1$, where $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0,1)$.
Being a linear transformation, it follows that $T(x, y) = (-y, x)$.

Now consider the basis $v_1 = (3, 0)$, $v_2 = (-2, 1)$. Then $Tv_1 = (0, 3) = 2 v_1 + 3 v_2$ and $Tv_2 = (-1,-2) = -5/3 v_1 -2 v_2$, so the matrix for $T$ in this basis is exactly
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -5/3\\ 3 & -2\end{pmatrix}.$$

You can also check that $PB = AP$ with
$$P = \begin{pmatrix}3 & -2\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$A,B$ are 'similar'  by $A = U^{-1} B V$ with invertible basis transforms $U,V$ in the two spaces.

Looking at the  central result, that the only invariant feature  of all  similar linear maps between two spaces ,  is the dimension of its kernel, that is the subspace of the preimage mapped to zero, 'similarity' certainly is a misleading formulation - at least in non-categorical language usage - that they all represent the same map in different bases.

Don't try to tell that deep truth to an optical specialist.

It's a classical case of Goethes view of pure mathematics
[Mathematicians are like frenchmen](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/40013-mathematicians-are-like-frenchmen-whatever-you-say-to-them-they)

The productive potential of the definition of similarity evolves if applied to multiple chains of linear maps,   characterized by their kernels and cokernels

Comment: This is all very good to keep in mind, but it gets me no closer to understanding the very basic things that I've yet to grasp. If I were to provide you with a pair of similar 2x2 matrices of my choosing, would you be willing to explain to me how I could go about convincing myself that they do in fact represent the same linear map? Also, I have no idea how to derive a basis from a matrix. But if I did know what the bases of similar matrices were, then I would of course know how to use the change of basis matrices to translate between them. My issue is what the bases are in the first place

Comment: Similar and same is not the same. Evidently, quadratic matrices fall into two different categories: endomorphisms as maps to a space onto itself, and linear maps between different spaces of the same dimension. For endomorphisms, to use different bases on both sides is not in the focus, only the multiplicity of the eigenvalue 0 and the construction of bases for the kernel is of interest. Similarity guarantees the algorithms to work by differntiating the different cases of dimensions of the kernel. Crucial only for infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that similar matrices are in general not identical. To quote wikipedia: "Similar matrices represent the same linear map under two (possibly) different bases". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity. What does this mean? And for example how exactly do $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\\ 1 &0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -5/3 \\\ 3 & -2\end{pmatrix}$$ represent the same linear map?